# Video as Description on the meta property og:video

Tags: html, video

I want to put a video as my description. Like when you share a link on some platforms  it appears a description what can be shown with the meta property "og:description".
Example: [discord example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeZeo.jpg)

I tried many ways:
-With the og:video and all the other optional property meta tags for it.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://bogdaan.ro/dacia.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://bogdaan.ro/dacia.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://bogdaan.ro/dacia.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="460">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="258">
```

I tried to put a video on the page with display: none; but it won't work.
My question is: How do I do it or what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, don't copy websites and take the copyright as your own. (bogdaan.ro is a copy of rmly.dev)

Second, this cannot be done with a video. You want to create an .html file, enter the meta there and make it redirect the video or put the video into an iframe. YouTube practically done the same thing.

Comment: Care-i problema ta prietene?

Comment: Please speak English. As far as i can understand you asked me what is my problem, i have no problem with you at all, just said what you've done and what you need to do.